# Edittext get null values in oncreate in android

Tags: android

```
EditText edituname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
EditText editpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    String s1 = edituname.getText().toString();
    String s2 = editpassword.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, s1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The string `s1` shows null value since the code is inside `onCreate` method. I want it in `onCreate` and not on `buttonclick`. So please tell me a solution to get the value of `EditText` in `onCreate`.

Comment: Post your whole activity code.

Comment: what will you do with this as it will always be null.

Comment: `Blank` Edit text will always gives you null values even if it is in `onCreate`. you can only get values after some inputs are done.

Comment: @jaydroider is right. What you are trying to do is simply not possible as text is not yet given

Comment: You can't, you are going to have to get the values on button click, that is the only way to assure that you are getting the values that are in the fields when the button is clicked. Outside of implementing a TextWatcher, but that is more than you need if you just want the value on button click.

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I solved the issue using intent.putExtra() method.

Answer (score 0):

The value of edittext will be null at the time of initialization thats why it is null. If you want the value without any button click you can set [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on edittext you want

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I solved the issue using intent.putExtra() method. But your valuable comment will be useful to me later in the project.